# Troubleshooting Simple Arduino Class

Tags: c++, class, arduino

I am trying to get a simple class library to work for an Arduino and am struggling.

Library - .h

```
#ifndef ADS1X15_h
#define ADS1X15_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class ADS1X15
{
    protected:

    public:
        ADS1X15     ();
        void        begin(uint8_t i2cAddress);
        uint8_t     m_i2cAddress;
        uint8_t     m_test;

    private:
};

#endif
```

Library .cpp

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "ADS1X15.h"

ADS1X15::ADS1X15() {
    uint8_t     m_i2cAddress;
    uint8_t     m_test = 99;
}

void ADS1X15::begin(uint8_t i2cAddress) {
    uint8_t     m_i2cAddress = i2cAddress;
}
```

Calling Sketch

```
#include <ADS1X15.h>

ADS1X15 ads; 

void setup(void) {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    ads.begin(66);
}

void loop(void) {
    Serial.print("Test1 ");
    Serial.println(ads.m_i2cAddress);
    Serial.print("Test2 ");
    Serial.println(ads.m_test);  
    while (1==1) {}
}
```

It seems the above should print 99 and 66 instead of 0 and 0!?!?!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
ADS1X15::ADS1X15() {
    uint8_t     m_i2cAddress;
    uint8_t     m_test = 99;
}
```

It declares two local variables to the constructor that match the names of your class members.  You have a similar error in `ADS1X15::begin`.  If you had warnings enabled, you should have gotten a warning about a local variable shadowing a member variable, or similar.

Rewrite those without the type declarations, and they'll update your class instead of updating local variables to the methods.

```
ADS1X15::ADS1X15() {
    m_test = 99;
}

void ADS1X15::begin(uint8_t i2cAddress) {
    m_i2cAddress = i2cAddress;
}
```

Comment: That does the trick.   Not sure what I was thinking or what example I was looking at and not seeing that.

Answer (score 1):

In your cpp:

```
ADS1X15::ADS1X15() {
    uint8_t     m_i2cAddress;
    uint8_t     m_test = 99;
```

you are redeclaring public members, so when you refer then inside constructor, you are acessing private copy instead of public class members.

Just use:

```
ADS1X15::ADS1X15() {
    m_test = 99;
}

void ADS1X15::begin(uint8_t i2cAddress) {
    m_i2cAddress = i2cAddress;
}
```